# Performance of Orderby Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary (string, UDT) where UDT is defined as

```
// simplified structure
class UDT
{
   public DateTime datetime;
   public double size;
};
```

I have to sort this dictionary by time and then by size very often. I am doing something like this now -

```
var result = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value.datetime).ThenBy(x => x.Value.size);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, UDT> val in result
{
}
```

The size of this dictionary is very large and most of the application bottleneck seems to be here. Is there any way to keep the dictionary sorted when items get added to the dictionary or to sort it more efficiently?

Comment: You need to sort by the value in a dictionary?  That is very inefficient.  How often do you have to re-sort the collection?  I'd either use a SortedDictionary with all of the values in the key (with a custom comparer), or put all of the values in a class that you use in a List<T> and sort (again, using a custom comparer) as needed.

Answer (score 2):

A more appropriate solution is to do what you're already doing by sorting when you *read* from the dictionary rather than keeping it sorted in memory. I would suggest caching the sorted result as a `List` though to reduce the amount of overhead.

Comment: SortedDictionary doesn't help here at all -- he's sorting by the value part of the pair, not the key.

Comment: @Joe - Updated with a possibly more appropriate answer.

Comment: It's no different -- he'll pay the same penalty either way.  The key is to try to maintain the proper sort order at insert, which will never happen with a Dictionary or SortedDictionary where the "keys" are in the value half of the pair.

Comment: @Joe - Is that really worth a downvote? I've edited again, though based on your response it probably still won't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to repeatedly sort by the items in the value part of a IDictionary, you're doing it wrong, at least with large datasets.

Use a container that either allows you to store the data at insertion time in the correct order (e.g. SortedList, using a custom comparer) or a List that you then .Sort on an as-needed basis (again, with a custom comparer).  It really depends on how often you are adding data and how often you need to re-sort.  You'd have to measure for this.